# Can a formula that has free variables be logically equivalent with a sentence?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\phi$ be a formula in F.O.L. that has free variables.

I wondered at first hand:

Can we always find a structure $\mathfrak C$ together with assignments $\alpha,\beta$ such that: $\mathfrak C\vDash\phi[\alpha]$ and $\mathfrak C\nvDash\phi[\beta]$?

I found counterexamples for that in formulas like $x=x$ and $\neg x=x$.

But the fact that in those cases we are dealing with a tautology and a contradiction respectively made me wonder: what if counterexamples of that sort are not allowed?

So I pose the question again, but under the extra condition that structures $\mathfrak A, \mathfrak B$ exists together with assignments $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfying $\mathfrak A\vDash\phi[\alpha]$ and $\mathfrak B\nvDash\phi[\beta]$.

If the answer is in that case a "no" then I can draw the conclusion that formulas that are not sentences but are logically equivalent with sentences must be tautologies or contradictions.

I do not know whether that is true (actually I hope so) or not (I do have my doubts), and am quite curious.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit**:

Let me for compleness make clear what definition  I practicize for *logical equivalence* of formulas.

Two formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if for every structure $\mathfrak A$ and every $\mathfrak A$-assignment $\alpha$:
$$\mathfrak A\vDash\phi\leftrightarrow\psi[\alpha]$$
or equivalently:$$\mathfrak A\vDash\phi[\alpha]\iff\mathfrak A\vDash\psi[\alpha]$$

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to rethink your question: the question in your title is rather different from what you are asking about in the body of the question. A formula with free variables can be logically to a sentence, but that doesn't seem to bear much relation to the body of your question.

Comment: @RobArthan My actual question is: can a formula that has free variables be logically equivalent with a sentence *that is not a tautology and not a contradiction*? I leaved the italics (which are made clear in the body) out. Is it clear that this is my question, or do you still propose a moderation of the title?

Comment: @drhab I have edited my answer to include an answer to the question in your comment.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Thank you, Mark. Later on the day (or maybe tomorrow) I will have a good look on your answer. Right I am too busy with my grandchildren :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix some theory $T$ in some language $\mathcal{L}$. If you wish to just consider structures you can take $T$ to be the empty theory (i.e. no axioms). We define two formulas $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ to be logically equivalent (modulo $T$) if
$$
T \models \forall x(\phi(x) \leftrightarrow \psi(x)).
$$
This is indeed equivalent to the definition you mention for the empty theory, and for non-empty theories it just restricts us to the models of $T$. Note that in the above definition $\phi$ and $\psi$ do not need to actually mention the variables $x$.

Your main question then was the following:

> Can a formula that has free variables be logically equivalent with a sentence that is not a tautology or a contradiction?

The answer is yes. Take any sentence $\psi$ that is not a tautology or contradiction. Then $\psi \wedge x = x$ is logically equivalent and has free variable $x$.

One example would be to take $\psi$ to be the sentence "there are at least 10 elements" and $T$ to be the empty theory. Then there will be structures (models of $T$) where $\psi$ is true and there will also be structures where $\psi$ is false, so $\psi$ is neither a tautology nor contradiction.

If every sentence is a tautology or contradiction (modulo $T$), so if $T$ is complete, then this can obviously not happen. Simply because there are no sentences that are not a tautology or contradiction.

Your original motivation was the following question:

> Given $\phi(x)$, can we find a structure $C$ and $a,b \in C$ such that $C \models \phi(a)$ and $C \not \models \phi(b)$?

You mentioned that if $\phi(x)$ is a tautology or contradiction then this cannot happen. Something more general is actually true: if $\phi(x)$ is logically equivalent to a sentence then this cannot happen. Because in such a case we have $C \models \phi(a)$ if and only if $C \models \psi$ if and only if $C \models \phi(b)$, making use of the fact that $C \models \psi$ does not depend on $a$ or $b$. This does not depend on the fact whether or not $\psi$ is a tautology or contradiction.

Finding structures $A$ and $B$ with elements $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $A \models \phi(a)$ and $B \not \models \phi(b)$ heavily depends on the theory $T$ and $\phi(x)$ (also when $A = B$).

Comment: The question is asking for a single model $\mathfrak{C}$ with a certain property.

Comment: @Rob From what I understood that is what they first wondered and already answered. Then some other questions were formulated, which I tried to address.

Comment: Isn't there more than one way for a model not to satisfy a predicate? Suppose A and B have do not have truth assignments for $\phi$, then $A \not \models \forall x \neg \phi(x)$ and $B \not \models \forall x \phi(x)$. However it may not be the case that there are $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $A \models \phi(a)$ and $B \not \models \phi(b)$.

Comment: @user400188 I'm not sure what you mean here. But if $A \not \models \forall x \neg \phi(x)$ then $A \models \neg \forall x \neg \phi(x)$, which is equivalent to $A \models \exists x \phi(x)$. Similar argument for $B$.

Comment: In an edit I made clear what I mean with logical equivalence of formulas. According to the definition that I practicize the formulas $x=c$ and $\forall x[x=c]$ are not logically equivalent. I suspect you to have another definition in mind. Maybe something like: $\mathfrak A\vDash\phi[\alpha] for every assignment $\alpha$ iff $\mathfrak A\vDash\psi[\alpha]$ for every assignment $\alpha$.

Comment: @drhab Ah, now I understand your question much better. I have fully revised my answer, hopefully this answers your question. There are actually quite a few ideas / questions in your post, but you clearly indicated a main question in the comments (might be good to edit the body of the question to emphasise that). Hopefully this answers that main question.

Comment: "Something more general is actually true: if $\phi(x)$ is logically equivalent to a sentence then this cannot happen." That fact (I realized it) is exactly what triggered me to pose the question in the body. Thanks. I feel a bit ashamed that I had a blind spot for the rather trivial solution $\psi\wedge x=x$ where $\psi$ is a sentence that is not a tautology and not a contradiction.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Just to clarify, it's not the case that if $A\nvDash\forall x\lnot\phi(x)$ then $A\vDash\lnot \forall x\lnot\phi(x)$. (1 of 3)

Comment: Consider the following example: If your theory is Robinsons arithmetic, and your structure contains the standard model of arithmetic, then your structure wont satisfy the sentence $i\times i\times i\times i=1\land i\neq 1$. On the other hand, if your structure contains a model for the imaginary numbers, then it will. (2 of 3)

Comment: Since both structures satisfy the same theory, and that theory is consistent, it cannot be the case that if $A\nvDash\forall x\lnot\phi(x)$ then $A\vDash\lnot \forall x\lnot\phi(x)$ is true. (3 of 3)

Comment: @user400188 You are confusing "$A \models$" for a structure $A$ with "$T \models$" for a theory $T$. In a structure $A$ we have by definition $A \models \neg \psi$ if $A \not \models \psi$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I am almost certain that you have this definition backwards. For a consistent model, if $A\models \lnot\psi$ then $A\not\models\psi$. (1 of 3)

Comment: My reference for this is (http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/model_theory.pdf), where the definition of a model is given under definition 8. Point 3 in particular talks about the conditional I am calling into question. (2 of 3)

Comment: To clarify what I first meant by "there is more than one way for a structure not to satisfy a theory": Consider that the structure $A$ does not have $\phi$ in its signature. Then it has no way to interpret $\phi$, and so $A\not\models\phi(x)$. However, because $\phi$ is not it the signature of $A$, it is not the case that $A\models \lnot\phi(x)$ either. (3 of 3)

Comment: @user400188 In the $\models$ relation we only consider formulas in the same signature as the structure (or theory). Asking whether or not $A \models \phi$ where $\phi$ uses symbols not in the signature of $A$ does not make sense, and is not defined. The source you mention agrees with the definition I wrote (remember that definitions are "if and only if").

Comment: @MarkKamsma Sorry, I read "means that" as "implies" rather than "iff" in the source. Thank you for your patience teaching me.

Comment: @user400188 You're welcome, happy to clear that up for you!